# Multiply two data frames with similar index in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames and I want to multiply them by index. What the best way to do this?
NOTE: Column names are different.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([(1,2,3),(3,4,5),(5,6,7)], columns=['a','b','d'], index = ['A', 'B','C'])
df1
   a  b  d
A  1  2  3
B  3  4  5
C  5  6  7

df2 = pd.DataFrame([(10,20,30)], columns=['A','B','C'],index = ['ss'])
df2 = df2.transpose()
df2
   ss
A  10
B  20
C  30
```

Output Dataframe:

```
     a   b   d
A   10  20  30
B   60  80 100
C  150 180 210
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html#pandas.DataFrame.mul) and convert the Series to a list and pass `axis=0`, by converting to a list we ignore any alignment errors with the index/column names:

```
In [74]:

df1.mul(list(df2['ss']), axis=0)
Out[74]:
     a    b    d
A   10   20   30
B   60   80  100
C  150  180  210
```

**EDIT**

No need to convert to a list just access the Series directly:

```
In [75]:

df1.mul(df2['ss'], axis=0)
Out[75]:
     a    b    d
A   10   20   30
B   60   80  100
C  150  180  210
```

Comment: Try with: df2 = pd.DataFrame([(10,20,30)], columns=['A','C', 'D'], index = ['ss']).T

Comment: @Alexander the OP has specifically posted examples where the 2 df's have the same indices

Comment: Agree with @EdChum here. Even with @Alexander's example you could still drop the non-matching indices right? `df1.mul(df2['ss'], axis='index').dropna()`

Comment: @Alexander by using that sample df none of the posted answer's work

Comment: True, just pointing out that this solution wouldn't work if they were different. @BrenBarn's solution works with the alternative df2 definition.

Comment: @Alexander saying that though my top half answer still works with the non-aligning df2 you proposed as the list data becomes anonymous with no index or column mis-alignment

Comment: @Alexander no I get the same errors using BrenBarn's method: `In [88]:

df2 = pd.DataFrame([(10,20,30)], columns=['A','C', 'D'], index = ['ss']).T
df1.mul(df2.squeeze(), axis='index')
Out[88]:
     a    b    d
A   10   20   30
B  NaN  NaN  NaN
C  100  120  140
D  NaN  NaN  NaN`

Comment: @Alexander Quite not, both BrenBarn and EdChum outputs are same.

Comment: Sorry, it is a Pandas version issue (v.14.1 vs 16.0)  The results are different with the older version: df1.mul(list(df2['ss']), axis=0)
     a    b    d
A   10   20   30
B   60   80  100
C  150  180  210

Answer (score 2):

One way could be to multiply on Numpy arrays like

```
In [8]: pd.DataFrame(df1.values*df2.values,
                      columns=['a','b','d'], index = ['A', 'B','C'])
Out[8]:
     a    b    d
A   10   20   30
B   60   80  100
C  150  180  210
```

Comment: This will create errors if the matrix and vector (df2) don't share the same index.

Comment: This leads to fail if number of rows are different

Answer (score 2):

If you want to multiply the one-column DF without regard for its column name, it's better to make it a Series, which you can do with the `.squeeze()` method.  Then:

```
>>> df1.mul(df2.squeeze(), axis='index')
      a    b    d
A   10   20   30
B   60   80  100
C  150  180  210
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the following output Dataframe, as above:

```
   a    b    d
A  10   20   30
B  60   80   100
C  150  180  210
```

... execute the following:

```
df3 = pandas.DataFrame(df1.values*df2.values, columns=df1.columns, index=df1.index)
```

This performs column-wise multiplication.

Comment: Does not work when number of rows of two dataframes are different.