# How do I multiply all elements of a column of a dataframe with value specified for that column in another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My question is quite similar to [Multiply two pandas DataFrames based on column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21685093/multiply-two-pandas-dataframes-based-on-column) and [Multiply two data frames with similar index in python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29856638/multiply-two-data-frames-with-similar-index-in-python-pandas) but a little different. I tried both the suggestions but it didn't work for me.

All my inputs are read from a csv file.

Input 1

```
   Attr1   Attr2
0     10      20
1     30      40
```

Assume Input 2 specifies weights for Attr1 and Attr2

Input 2

```
   Attr1   Attr2
0     5        6
```

My output would be multiplying the weights from Input 2 to every row of that corresponding attribute in Input 1 so my output needs to be

```
   Attr1   Attr2
0     50     120
1    150     240
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can first select first row in `d2` - output is `Series` and then multiple by [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html):

```
print (d2.iloc[0])
Attr1    5
Attr2    6
Name: 0, dtype: int64

d = d1.mul(d2.iloc[0])
print (d)
   Attr1  Attr2
0     50    120
1    150    240
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a possible solution:

```
import pandas as pd


d1 = pd.DataFrame([[10, 20], [30, 40]], columns=['Attr1', 'Attr2'])
d2 = pd.DataFrame([[5, 6]], columns=['Attr1', 'Attr2'])

# iterate over columns of the second dataframe
for col in d2.columns: 
    # you can check whether col is in d1 
    # if col in d1.columns:
    d1[col] = d1[col] * d2[col][0]
```